# Grails Count By does not return correct value

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, count, hql

I am trying to return the total count of items in by database using Grails Count By
The query that I have is

```
def string  = "'%"+params.query+"%'"
def sqlquery ="SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Document WHERE status= '"+params.Status+"' And doc_name LIKE "+string;
total = Document.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

This should return me the total count but it is  returning 0 instead of 724
I also tried something like

```
total = Document.countByStatusAndDocNameLike(params.docStatus,string);
```

but getting 0 instead of 724

which is wierd because this returns correct value

```
def sqlquery ="SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Document WHERE doc_name LIKE "+string;
total = Document.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

Comment: What does `params.Status` contain or can contain? It may corrupt your SQL (e.g. if it contains `'`). You need to escape Strings passed to SQL queries or use Prepared Queries instead.

Comment: it can contain New,Reviewed,In-progress string

Comment: Your DB is case sensitive or insensitive?

Comment: def sqlquery ="SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Document WHERE status = :stat AND doc_name LIKE "+string;
    total = Document.executeQuery(sqlquery,[stat:params.Status]); works for me

Answer (score 0):

So, if these two:

```
def sqlquery ="SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Document WHERE status= '"+params.Status+"' And doc_name LIKE "+string;
total = Document.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

and

```
total = Document.countByStatusAndDocNameLike(params.docStatus,string);
```

return the same thing (and they should), but the count they return is 0, yet this:

```
def sqlquery ="SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM Document WHERE doc_name LIKE "+string;
total = Document.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

returns all the docs you expect, then I must suggest that the docs you expect do NOT have the status in params.Status .   I suggest printing out what the value of params.Status is, and see if it matches... exactly... the values in the 724 docs you're expecting back.  Note that COUNT(Status) in the last query isn't counting the ones that have params.Status in it (as params.Status isn't mentioned in the query)... that might as well say COUNT(*).